# Unet Binary Classification question: any difference for label background as 0, target as 1 or label background as 1 and target as 0? Thank you

Tags: deep-learning, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

A beginner question as above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is customary to label the background as 0, and I can not think of a reason why you should label the background as 1. That being said, if you specify 1 as being background before you run the model then 1 will also be the label for background class after you run your model.